# Property backupdirectory is not available for settings 'microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.settings'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to create a database from a .bak file. While connected to my localhost, I right click on 'Restore Database'. In the 'Restore Database' dialog, I then click on the "Device" radio button.

I click the ... button to open the 'Select backup devices' dialog.  Click 'Add', and then navigate to the location of the .bak file. I select the file and then click 'okay' and then 'okay' again.

At this point, I get this error:

[image]

Via Google, I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3ba6d023-5899-4c5a-9270-87792840a3ba/insufficient-access-rights-error-when-doing-backup?forum=sqlsmoanddmo).  I wasn't sure where I should add the key, so added it twice:

[image]

[image]

But, that didn't seem to d the trick.  I still get the same error.

Did I do this wrong?  Or, what else do I need to do?  (Oh, and the folder C:\SQLBackup exists, and I gave 'Everyone' full rights to it.)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:

http://superpctricks.com/property-backupdirectory-is-not-available-for-settings

I needed to add the `BackupDirectory` value in the local install instance inside RegEdit.  See the link for instructions.